# Valence API call results in redirection to /d2l/error/500

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to use one of D2L's Valence Learning Framework API calls, and the service is redirecting my call (with a 302 or 303) to `/d2l/error/500`. Why is this? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your API call has provoked the back-end LMS into having a service exception of some kind. If you encounter this, you should:

1. Engage the administrator of your back-end LMS service to capture system logs around the time of your API call(s), in order get a trace of the execution path that caused the error. It may also prove quite valuable if you can capture a trace of exactly the HTTP(s) API call that you made (URL, headers, body), and exactly the response packet you received back.
2. Work with your organization's Approved Support Contact, or your Partner Manager, to contact [Desire2Learn's support desk](https://helpdesk.desire2learn.com/) and report this as a support incident. You should specifically inform the support desk that you have encountered a service exception while using the Valence Learning Framework APIs, and if you can provide them with the traces you've gathered, this will be very helpful.